# How to get reference to json key name inside {{#with}} helper?

Tags: handlebars.js

I want to draw fields using a Handlebars partial that have the key name and value. My json is like this:

`{ "someKnownField" : { "textValue" : "the value I want" } }`

I want a label with `someKnownField` as its text, and an input with the value of `textValue` in it. I use a partial because I have hundreds of these fields and don't want to have to hard code their names.

Here's my partial code, called `textfield`

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="input{{@key}}">{{@key}}</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="input{{@index}}" placeholder="{{@key}}" value="{{textValue}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I can't use a `{{#with}}` helper, a-la `{{#with someKnownField}}{{> textfield}}{{/with}}` since a with doesn't give you a `@key`. `{{#each}}` has a `@key` but its of the context within the each node (`textValue`); So how do you key the key name OF the each node itself?

This does not work, but demonstrates what I need to grab:

```
<label>{{../@key}}</label>
```

since it's expecting an id in the parent path, not a calculated value (which doesn't exist anyway, since it's not an array itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done well, but made a typo. The correct way:

```
<label>{{@../key}}</label>
```